# Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. Unable to continue with install: ClusterRole "prometheus-kube

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-operator, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. Unable to continue with install: ClusterRole "prometheus-kube-state-metrics" in namespace "" exists and cannot be imported into the current release: invalid ownership metadata; annotation validation error: key "meta.helm.sh/release-namespace" must equal "monitoring": current value is "monitoring-kogito-poc"

How to resolve this I have deleted the namespace and created new namespace and trying to install helm charts for grafana and prometheus.
But it couldn't allowed me to install.
I have deleted clusterrolebinding to for all below enter image description here

kubectl delete clusterrolebinding prometheus-kube-state-metrics
[enter image description here][1]

but it still showing and notable install prometheus
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkNaS.png

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 7):

It was not enough just to delete the role binding. I had to also delete the role itself.

```
kubectl delete clusterrole prometheus-kube-state-metrics
```

Furthermore I deleted all other prometheus-relevant role bindings and roles, too:

- prometheus-alertmanager
- prometheus-pushgateway
- prometheus-server
- system:prometheus

Finally I re-ran the installation and it worked.

Comment: same issue as above ?

Comment: clusterrole:
kubectl get clusterroles | grep operators
kubectl delete clusterroles prometheus-alertmanager | grep operators
kubectl get clusterroles | grep olm
kubectl delete clusterroles aggregate-olm-edit aggregate-olm-view | grep olm

clusterrolebindings:
 kubectl get clusterrolebindings | grep operator
kubectl delete clusterrolebindings kogito-operator-manager-rolebinding | grep operator
kubectl get clusterrolebindings | grep operators

customresourcedefinition :
kubectl delete customresourcedefinition clusterserviceversions.operators.coreos.com | grep operators

Comment: clusterrole: >>>kubectl get clusterroles | grep operators.      $>>> kubectl delete clusterroles prometheus-alertmanager | grep operators . $>>>kubectl get clusterroles | grep olm. $>>>kubectl delete clusterroles aggregate-olm-edit aggregate-olm-view | grep olm

Comment: find the clusterrolebindings and delete : $>>>kubectl get clusterrolebindings | grep operator. $>>>> kubectl delete clusterrolebindings kogito-operator-manager-rolebinding | grep.
Try to re-install

Comment: customresourcedefinition : $>>>>>kubectl get customresourcedefinition  | grep operators. $>>>>>kubectl delete customresourcedefinition clusterserviceversions.operators.coreos.com | grep operators

Answer (score 0):

you can sue following command to set namespace context, it will set the current namespace context

```bash
kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=my_ns
```